# Forcing LSF to execute jobs on different hosts

Tags: lsf

I have a setup consisting from 3 workers and a management node, which I use for submitting tasks. I would like to execute concurrently a setup script at all workers:

```
bsub -q queue -n 3 -m 'h0 h1 h2' -J "%J_%I" mpirun setup.sh
```

As far as I understand, I could use 'ptile' resource constraint to force execution at all workers:

```
bsub -q queue -n 3 -m 'h0 h1 h2' -J "%J_%I" -R 'span[ptile=1]' mpirun setup.sh
```

However, occasionally I face an issue that my script got executed several times at the same worker.

Is it expected behavior? Or there is a bug in my setup? Is there a better way for enforcing multi worker execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of `span[ptile=1]` is correct.  LSF will only use 1 core per host for your job.  If there aren't enough hosts based on the `-n` then the job will pend until something frees up.

> However, occasionally I face an issue that my script got executed
>   several times at the same worker.

I suspect that its something with your script.  e.g., LSF *appends* to the stdout file by default. Use `-oo` to overwrite.